# Get all subids of mysql child nodes

Tags: mysql, sql

we have a `mysql` table where we have

```
id | parent_id | item
```

lets say I have an `id=4`

I need to get all items whos `parent_id=4`

After I need all subitems where `parent_id IN(the ids i got up)`

then again and again till `6 levels`

Any ideas how to get those with one query?

Comment: So you need to like to recursively (with a depth of 6) retrieve data from data?

Comment: yes, but not to the UP , but to the DOWN...

Answer (score 1):

You should at least attempt this before asking for someone to do the work for you but something like this might work...

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id, ... INNER JOIN table t6 ON t5.id = t6.parent_id
WHERE t1.id=4
```

Comment: This is when you go from down to UP, but I need from upper level to down.. Should be a lot if IN()s IMHO

Comment: Imagine you have 2 sublevels they have each 2-3 sublevels and those  5-6 have each any qty of sublevels. and I need get all Ids of those sublevels under me

Comment: I don't think you need any "IN"s you just need to join on all the "id"s that you got and if there are multiple "id"s it will join on multiple values.  Unless you are trying to join the tables in the WHERE clause which I don't believe would be the correct way to do this, then you can't use "IN"s in the FROM clause

Comment: also I believe this is the upper to lower approach.  You start with "id=4", then you join the next table where "parent_id=4", then you join the next table where "parent_id=(all ids where the parent id was 4)" and so on...I am pretty sure this should get you the result you are looking for based on your original question...however I have no such DB to test on